# angular 5 async validator not working

Tags: angular5

I am validating if mobile number exist on server in angular 5.Si i have created a custom async validator for this.But it is not working nor giving any error and it gives pending status to form field.Any help will be appreciated.here is code of service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class SignupService {

constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {}
mobileExists(mobile:number):Observable<{}>{
return this._http.get("http://localhost/truck/api/web/user/verify-              exist?mobile="+mobile,{responseType:'json'});
}
}
```

and here is code of my component.ts

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,AbstractControl, ValidationErrors,FormControl,Validators,FormGroup,AsyncValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";
        import {SignupService} from "./signup.service";
        import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
        import {map,take,debounceTime} from "rxjs/operators";

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-register',
          templateUrl: './register.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
          providers: [SignupService]
        })
        export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
            signupForm: FormGroup;
            mobile: number;
            password: string;
            otp: number;
            public exist;

            constructor(public service:SignupService) {
            }

            ngOnInit() {
                this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
                    mobile: new FormControl('',
                        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)],this.mobileValidator.bind(this)),
                    password: new FormControl('',
                        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15)]),
                    otp: new FormControl('',
                        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(6)]),
                });
            }

            mobileValidator(control: AbstractControl):any {

                return new Observable(resolve => {
                        this.service.mobileExists(control.value).subscribe(
                            data=>{
                                if (data['status'] == 'ok'){
                                    return null;
                                }else if(this.exist.status == 'exist'){
                                    return {mobileTaken:true};
                                }
                            },
                            error=>{
                             return   console.log(error)
                            },

                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: returned data from api is a json array like {'status':'ok'}

Answer (score 3):

1. In FormControl use `mobile: new FormControl('',
                       [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)],[this.mobileValidator()]),` so **AsyncValidator** as third parameter and no need to call bind.
2. Use map and no need to wrap to new Observable call: `mobileValidator() { return (control: AbstractControl): any => { return this.service.mobileExists(control.value).map(data => return (data['status'] == 'ok') ? null : { mobileTaken: true } )); } }`

   3. good article is here http://fiyazhasan.me/asynchronous-validation-in-angulars-reactive-forms-control/

Comment: How can you catch other status code than 200 in map? I tried it and if status code is other than 200 it wont work.

Comment: @karoluS use catchError((err: any) => {...}) in your pipe